# Get error org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException: Can't find a codec for class example.micronaut.entity.Fruit

Tags: java, micronaut, micronaut-data, micronaut-mongodb

**Steps to reproduce**

1. Download source from https://guides.micronaut.io/latest/micronaut-data-mongodb-asynchronous-maven-java.zip
2. Add a new test class under package `example.micronaut.some.other` named **SomeOtherTest**
3. Change **Fruit** class package to `example.micronaut.entity`
4. Change **FruitRepository** class package to `example.micronaut.repository`

**Environment**

1. Operating System: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
2. JDK "17.0.1" 2021-10-19 LTS
3. Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server

For error snapshot, do refer `https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-guides/issues/928`

Is some micronaut configuration/ tags missing? I am trying to avoid creating a Micronaut codec class since I make use of only primitive data types!

I have basically found no way out, hence a quick help/ pointer would greatly help.

Answer (score 3):

If you put your entities outside of the application package, you need to specify it in the mongo configuration:

```yaml
mongodb:
  package-names:
    xyz
```